# how to recognize objects touched in a table in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

say I have a table view in corona with a cell that has these three objects with different ids, I can recognize the row touch, but how do I recognize the objects touched inside the table view?

[image]

this is the code i'm using

```
local function onRowRender( event )
  local row = event.row
  local rowHeight = row.contentHeight
  local rowWidth = row.contentWidth

  local speaker1 = display.newImage(row,"images/listen.png",70,70)
  speaker1.width = 20;speaker1.height = 20*ryx
  speaker1.x = 35;speaker1.y = suby
  speaker1.id = "speaker1"

  local eye1 = display.newImage(row,"images/eye.png",70,70)
  eye1.width = 20;eye1.height = 20*ryx
  eye1.x = 60;eye1.y = suby
  eye1.id = "eye1"

  speaker1:addEventListener("touch",onObjectTouch)
  eye1:addEventListener("touch",onObjectTouch)

end
```

and

```
local function onRowTouch( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    local row = event.target

    touchedRowIndex = row.index

    print(event.target.id)
    print(event.target)
    print(event.target.name)


  if ( "release" == phase ) then
    return true
  end
end
```

I tried using touch listener for each object, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 speaker1:addEventListener("touch",onObjectTouch)
  eye1:addEventListener("touch",onObjectTouch)
```

Here you add the EventListener `onObjectTouch` but you implemented `onRowTouch`.

You should implement `onObjectTouch` or rename the EventListener added.